# Extract a text from the given word till the end of paragraph with regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am learning to work with regular expressions, and here the task I have:
The text is a chat between two people

"
Anton: I need staff ....
........................
.................... now

Antor: Ok.
"

I need to find first text after word 'need'(and "needed", or "needing") till the end of the paragraph.

My code gives 'none':

```
with open('pars_text2.txt', 'r') as pars_text2:
    conversation = pars_text2.read()
pattern=r'^(all.need[,\s]*)'
second=re.match(pattern, conversation)
print(second)
```

And it should give the string "need staff ....
........................
.................... now".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by the end of the paragraph you mean the single empty line, you might a capturing group:

```
^.*?(\b(?:need(?:ed|ing)?)\b.*(?:(?!\n[ \t]*$)\n.*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline non greedy
- `(` Capturing group (This will contain your value)

  - `\b(?:need(?:ed|ing)?)\b` Match need, needed or needing
  - `.*` Match any char except a newline
  - `(?:(?!\n[ \t]*$)\n.*)*` Repeat 0+ times matching the whole line while asserting using a negative lookahead that what follows immediately is not an empty line
- `)` Close capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/blvtJE/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Gub7NQ)

Comment: Did you try it like this? https://ideone.com/Gub7NQ Beside `return None` what does it print?

Comment: 'with open('pars_text2.txt', 'r') as pars_text2:
 conversation = pars_text2.read()
print(conversation)
pattern=r'^.*?(\b(?:need(?:ed|ing)?)\b.*(?:(?!\n[ \t]*$)\n.*)*)'
second=re.match(pattern, conversation)
print(second)' return None

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @LearntoFly Try using findall like `second = re.findall(pattern, conversation, re.M) print(second[0])`

Comment: second = re.findall(pattern, conversation) - 
It gives the empty list []
I understand that I make some basic mistake, but can't figure out which one

Comment: @LearntoFly Did you use the multiline flag `re.M`?

Comment: That's work fine! Thanks, now I'll try to understand what did I do wrong.